# Laravel pass value both as admin and normal user

Tags: php, laravel

I have a site where an admin can register themselves. Currently there is only one admin so the functions below works for passing the value:

```
public function getAllVideos()
{
    $videos = Video::all();
    $price = DB::table('donor')->sum('amount_donated');
    $goal = auth()->user()->goal;

    return view('adminmanagement', compact('videos', 'price', 'goal'));
}

public function changeGoal(Request $data)
{
    auth()->user()->update([
        'goal' => $data->input('newGoal')
    ]);

    return redirect('/home');
}
```

> And if I need to just pass it to a view where a normal user can see,
>   **do I do the following?**

```
public function getAllVideos()
    {
        $videos = Video::all();
        $price = DB::table('donor')->sum('amount_donated');
```

> `User::first()->goal;`

```
        return view('adminmanagement', compact('videos', 'price', 'goal'));
    }

    public function changeGoal(Request $data)
    {
        auth()->user()->update([
            'goal' => $data->input('newGoal')
        ]);

        return redirect('/normalview');
    }
```

But what if there are more than one registered users (admin) in the system. Would it still be fine as only one admin is logged in at a time? Or does the code need to change?

**EDIT:**
I have registration only for admins (which are 'user'), the normal users ( which are  'donors' in my case) don't have any registration/logging needed. So my main purpose is to be able to pass that $goal value to two different pages. One accessbile to admin(let's say a registered and logged in admin named jon), and other accessible to the normal user. so my current code 'User::first()->goal;' should do the trick, right? but, will it be fine if lets say, another admin named jim registers and logs in. So now the admin that is logged in is jim, not jon *will it still display the $goal value in the admin's view page(accessed by jim) and normal user's view page(accessed by a normal/random person)?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your other question you said that there's only one user and it's an admin. In that case you could replace the `auth()->user()` with `User::first()`. But if you have more than one admin or users, you need to specify the user using `User::find(1)` with the user id. Every user has a goal field and i assume you want to fetch only the goal from the admin user with the actual value. If so you can do this.

Replace

```
$goal = auth()->user()->goal;
```

With

```
$goal = User::find(1)->goal;
```

Make sure to use the user id of the user with the goal value.

Comment: could you please check my EDIT section I just added and let me know if your answer still matches with it. Thanks

Comment: U can have multiple admins, but you need to store the goal value with only one admin user and use that to display. So use `User::find(1)->goal;` to be safer and replace 1 with the admin user id in which you want to store the goal.

Comment: To be honest, the correct implementation is to have a separate table for goal and use that to store or fetch, Instead of storing the goal value with a user.

Comment: so would 'User::find(1)->goal;' be fine or should I create a new table? I could create one but then I have no idea how to do the passing of value. Also find(1) means getting the first value from User or is it referring to the id?

Comment: It's referring to the user id. If it's a simple a simple application then your fine with this.

Comment: just realised, how do I pass the value to the normal view. I mean the changeGoal() function redirects to '/home' which goes to getAllVideos() and does its work. But i need changeGoal to reidrect to the /normalview as well as /home...or through any means the compact(goal) should not be only for adminmanagement view but for another view also.how do i do that?

Comment: @AJth you can just fetch all the data from db like  in `getAllVideos` in you new method and use it.

Comment: but the form calls only one action that leads to the change-goal action that in turn leads to the getAllVideos which shows the view with the value passed...if i use a new method, i will need another form,right? but i want to be able to save from the same form

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145189/discussion-between-sandeesh-and-ajth).

Answer (score 1):

retrieving user via `auth()->user()` Or `Auth::user()`(I prefer the second way) only return the current logged user.

If you write : 
`Auth::user()->username` it will display their own name to all user viewing this page.

No need to worry :)

However, `User::first()` will get the first reccord in the `users` table so it will always be the same user and it may be a normal user

Comment: please check my EDIT in my questions

Comment: As i said in my reply, `User::first()` will only retrieve the first reccord of your table. This means you will always retrieve the same goal event from different page.
You should store or pass a parameter with the id of the wanted admin user